# Changing the default setting of a WinForms control property

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I seek to change the default setting of a .NET Windows Forms control's property, *without* creating a custom control inheriting from it.

What I want is, for example, to add a `TextBox` on my `Form` that already has the `TextAlign` property set to `HorizontalAlignment.Right` instead of `HorizontalAlignment.Left`. Even if only solution-wide, if achievable, I would love to know. This would save a lot of time for when one is working with a LOT of controls and needs to set their properties to specific, non-default, values.

Creating a custom control is just too overkill for this, and would clutter my solution with unnecessary things. I have also considered running a regex on the designer files solution-wide (to add the non-default values to such controls), but writing regex like that can (also) be time consuming/problematic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do that. But you need to set the binding initially. Later on you can set in one go to all the controls of your choice. This might be not your exact answer but this is how we define styles like as in WPF
(1) Click the Application Property Bindings

[image]

(2) Define Binding
[image]

[image]

(3)Now for textbox you can set the initial default
[image]
(4) Now You can set the property binding of every textbox intially or you can code which will set the application settings at starup or on form load.
This will you help to change the default propety at once later on

Comment: Wow. So simple, so convenient, this is *exactly* what I was looking for! I thought it wasn't possible without heavy duty intervention, but again my fellow SO users manage to surprise me. Many thanks.

Comment: you are welcome.  we are on earth to help each other.